# How to Deal with OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error on using place autocomplete API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to make a place search function with "Google place autocomplete api" in my android application. When i type just "gl", the API shows me autocompleted place successfully. But on typing "gle", it occurs OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

I found this policy about query limit in google document and i understood.
"Rate limit is 100 requests per second (QPS). It is calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side requests for all applications using the credentials of the same project."

But i typed "gle" at intervals of one second on purpose.

Is there any way to deal with OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in android or Can i appy debouncing or throttling on autocomplete querying ?

Perhaps, the only solution is paying price..?

I've tried restricted region and RectangularBounds.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
  val bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
            LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
            LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596)
        )

  val fields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG)

  val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields
  ).setLocationBias(
      RectangularBounds.newInstance(
        LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
        LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596)
       ).setCountry("au")
            .setLocationBias(bounds)
            .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
            .build(this)startActivityForResult(intent, 
  AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)

  startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
...
}
```

I expect showing continuous autocompleted suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> Please ensure that u have enabled billing account..